# How to change data in some situations?

Tags: vue.js

I have parent and child components.

In parent component I have the following code:

```
            <div v-for="(image, index) in images" class="col-md-4">
                <photo :index="index" :src ="image.src" :symbolId="image.symbol_id" :photoId="image.photo_id"></photo>
            </div>
    methods: {

        prepareCollage(){
            event.preventDefault();
            const self = this;
            axios.get('/api/prepare?query='+encodeURIComponent(this.text))
                .then(function(result){
                    const result_data = result.data;

                    if(result_data.error === true){
                        // here error code
                    }else{

                     
                       self.images = result_data.images;

                    }

            });
        },

    }
```

While, in my child component I have the following:

```
<template>
<div>
    <img v-on:click="replaceImage()" :src="mutatedSrc" class="img-responsive 
      image" :data-symbol-id="mutatedSymbolId" :data-photo-id="mutatedPhotoId">
    <input :name="mutatedIndex" :data-index="mutatedIndex" :data-symbol-id="mutatedSymbolId" :data-photo-id="mutatedPhotoId" type="hidden" :value="mutatedSrc">
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'photo',
    props: {
        src: {
            type : String,
            required: true
        },
        symbolId: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        photoId: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        index : {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            mutatedSrc: this.src,
            mutatedSymbolId: this.symbolId,
            mutatedPhotoId: this.photoId,
            mutatedIndex: this.index
        }
    },
    methods: {
        replaceImage(){
            const self = this;
            let arr_properties = { "sex" : 0, "nation" : 0, "color" : 0, "type" : 0};

            axios.get('/api/replace?photo_id='+this.mutatedPhotoId+'&symbol_id='+this.mutatedSymbolId+'&number='+this.mutatedIndex)
                .then(function(result){
                   self.mutatedSrc = result.data[0].photo_src;
                   self.mutatedPhotoId = result.data[0].photo_id;
                   self.mutatedSymbolId = result.data[0].photo_symbol_id;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

But under such condition my data changes only at a call of function `replaceImage ()`. I need change data when new prop `symbolId != old` prop `symbolId`.

For example, I have photo with following props:

```
[src => 1.jpg, symbolId => 1, photoId => 1, index = 1]
```

and when my parent component changes with following params

```
[src => 2.jpg, symbolId => 2, photoId => 2, index = 2]
```

I need to change my data.

Comment: can you clearly little bit what you consider as `new prop symbolId` and what as  `old prop symbolId`

Comment: I have some text input. After entering the text, I send an axios request from the parent component and backend gives me pictures. Each picture comes in the form of an array and consists of 3 elements src, photoId, symbolId. The problem is when I enter for example the text "hello" and then I change some letters in the word "helld" for example, then the picture "O" does not change to the picture "D". In this case, pictures have different symbolId

Comment: The edit to your post, made and approved some time ago, makes it **considerably better**. I'm not sure why you rejected it, but I have now "rolled back" your rejection and restored that good edit.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)ers on your props to set the `data` items from the props.

```
watch: {
  src(newValue) {
    this.mutatedSrc = newValue;
  },
  symbolId(newValue) {
    this.symbolId = newValue;
  },
  photoId(newValue) {
    this.mutatedPhotoId = newValue;
  },
  index(newValue) {
    this.mutatedIndex = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok. when i try do this http://joxi.ru/p27WDzlsoq0Xb2 i get a error Computed property "srcNew" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: At me the beginning to turn out, pictures change, but I constantly get an error in the console 

"Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "src""

http://joxi.ru/MAj38WvF49vpwr

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had two answers there. Only the top part applied to your situation. Since your values mutate, you will want to have data items. You just need an initialize method that you call when the props change.

Comment: Okay, but my problem is not solved. 
Now my pictures change when I change the text and when I call replaceImage (). But when changing the text, I need to compare the symbolId which was before and which is new. And only if they are not equal to change the picture

Comment: Where is the text that changes? How does it change, and how does that cause the image to change? Do you need to put an `if` of some kind around your `axios` call?

Comment: I have a text input. After entering the text, I send a request with the axioms from the parent component, and the backend gives me photos. Each image is represented as an array and consists of three elements src, photoId, symbolId. The problem is that, for example, I entered the text "hello", and then, for example, I change one or more letters in a word, for example, "helld". I need that, in the component, the property values ​​change only for the letter O and all the other letters "hell" remain unchanged

Comment: I think that issue is separate from the specific issue in your question and is related to the way your parent is architected. There is a lot of the parent we don't see here, so you probably need to ask a new question. I suspect that in your assignment to `self.images` you need to check that the `symbolId` has changed for each image.